# DVIPNG on MikTex

Tags: miktex, dvi, anki

I know a similar question has been asked before for something want to get DVIPNG for their Iguanatex but it appears the question was never answered.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177032/cannot-find-dvipng-sty-but-miktex-installed-package

I am trying to use the flashcard software Anki but I am trying to typeset some Tex on it and it requires DVIPNG which is apparently  already installed. It doesn't appear on the package manager but when I check the "Packages" section on the "MikTex Options", it appears to be installed as part of the "MikTex 2.9 executables(windowsx86)". I install packages on the fly and I thought that if I compile a document with \usepackage{dvipng} it would ask me whether to install the package or not.

I've reinstalled MikTex and yet it still fails. It would be greatly appreciated if someone with a greater understanding can help me out.

Comment: dvipng is an executable (dvipng.exe) not a style.  You need to compile a `file.tex` with latex to get a `file.dvi`, and then call (e.g. on a command line) `dvipng file.dvi`

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand it completely but I am going to give it a try. Thank you!